# D3py multiple graphs in same output

Tags: python, html, d3.js, graph, d3py

I would like to know how I can obtain multiple graphs as output on a single html page using d3py. I have been working with some of the examples in https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py, but when I try to get 2 or 3 graphs in a single output html file, it does not work.